# Cannot refresh ViewPager content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This code is very simple. I have a ViewPager with several Fragment inside. And a "Add new pager" button to add new pager to the first position of ViewPager.

Here is my code

```
public class TestPagerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private TestPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.testpager);

        mData.add("Looking");
        mData.add("into");
        mData.add("your");
        mData.add("dark");
        mData.add("blue");
        mData.add("eyes");
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TestPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mData);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void onAddNewPagerClick(View v) {
        mData.add(0, "When");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mPager.invalidate();
    }

    public static class TestPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private List<String> mData;

        public TestPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public TestPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> data) {
            super(fm);
            mData = data;
        }

        public void updateAdapter(List<String> data) {
            mData = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return TestFragment.newInstance(mData.get(position), position + "/" + mData.size());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

    }

    public static class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {
        private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";
        private static final String KEY_POSITION = "TestFragment:Position";

        public static TestFragment newInstance(String content, String position) {
            TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("Page ").append(position).append("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                builder.append(content).append(" ");
            }
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
            fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

            return fragment;
        }

        private String mContent = "???";
        private String mPosition = "x/y";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
                mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                mPosition = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_POSITION);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setText(mContent);
            text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layout.addView(text);

            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
            outState.putString(KEY_POSITION, mPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: when I refresh the ViewPager after adding a new pager, its content doesn't display correctly. At the beginning, I have 6 pages, but after adding a new one, there are still 6 pages displayed here while I expect 7 pages.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that stands out is that you're inserting new items at the front of your list of pages, yet you haven't implemented the PagerAdapter method [`getItemPosition(Object)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition%28java.lang.Object%29) to tell the ViewPager where pages have moved after a data set change. As the method's documentation states, the default implementation reports that pages never change positions. A ViewPager with pages that change position will not behave properly if your adapter does not correctly implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

**avoid FragmentPagerAdapter and use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.**

I hope it will work for you also.